# Find the order that substrings are mentioned in text

Tags: python, regex

'I have a list of substrings (each can be multiple tokens long) I want to search for in some text as an example, let's say my list of substrings is:

```
[
    'apple',
    'banana smoothie',
    'citrus orange fruit'
]
```

I also have a list of pieces of text which may contain none, some or all of the substrings, here are a couple of possible examples:

```
[
    'I like apple',
    'I like apple and banana smoothie',
    'I like banana smoothie, apple and citrus orange fruit',
    'I like none',
    'I like citrus orange fruit and apple'
]
```

I want to return the instances of the substrings mentioned in each text and what order they appear in, so for this example the output I want would be:

```
[    
    ['apple']
    ['apple', 'banana smoothie'],
    ['banana smoothie', 'apple', 'citrus orange fruit'],
    [],
    ['citrus orange fruit', 'apple']
]
```

I can only imagine doing this with some kind of sliding window approach, but I hope there is a simpler solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `re.findall` should already handle this requirement:

```
terms = ['apple', 'banana smoothie', 'citrus orange fruit']
inp = 'I like banana smoothie, apple and citrus orange fruit'
regex = r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(terms) + r')\b'
matches = re.findall(regex, inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['banana smoothie', 'apple', 'citrus orange fruit']
```

The reason this works is because the list of matches will be populated, left to right, as the input is parsed, maintaining the original ordering.

Comment: Perfect, didn't know this, and thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a regex from your list of search strings, and then use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to find all occurrences of those strings in each text:

```
import re

search = [
    'apple',
    'banana smoothie',
    'citrus orange fruit'
]

regex = re.compile(r'\b' + '|'.join(search) + r'\b', re.I)

text = [
    'I like apple',
    'I like apple and banana smoothie',
    'I like banana smoothie, apple and citrus orange fruit',
    'I like none',
    'I like citrus orange fruit and apple'
]

res = [regex.findall(t) for t in text]

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[
 ['apple'],
 ['apple', 'banana smoothie'],
 ['banana smoothie', 'apple', 'citrus orange fruit'],
 [],
 ['citrus orange fruit', 'apple']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that words is the list of words you provided and strings is the list of strings, this should work for you:

```
def getSequence(words, string):
    sequence = dict()
    for word in words:
        try:
            sequence[string.index(word)] = word
        except:
            pass

    indices = list(sequence.keys())
    indices.sort()

    return [sequence[idx] for idx in indices]

for string in strings:
    print(getSequence(words, string))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```py
>>> [[sub for sub in substrings if sub in s] for s in strings]
[['apple'], ['apple', 'banana smoothie'], ['apple', 'banana smoothie', 'citrus orange fruit'], [], ['apple', 'citrus orange fruit']]
```

Assuming `substrings` is your list of substrings, and `strings` is your list of full strings.

Comment: There is a bug in your solution: the substring `apple` is part of string `apples` but it shouldn't be returned.